# How to pass multiple incoming tags in single output tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

We have a GivenName field which comes as multiple tag in input. for ex:

```
    <PersonName>
      <Surname>BNWHBQQ</Surname>
      <GivenName>Adam</GivenName>
      <GivenName>Sam</GivenName>
      <GivenName>Peter</GivenName>
    </PersonName>
```

we need to concatenate all GivenName present in input and pass it in one tag, for ex:

```
    <db:PR_OFFENDER>
        <db:SURNAME>BNWHBQQ</db:SURNAME>
        <db:GIVEN_NAME>Adam Sam Peter</db:GIVEN_NAME>
    </db:PR_OFFENDER>
```

I tried:
I tried using for loop but thats of no use as i am getting multiple  in output as well, something like:

```
<xsl:if test="out:PartyEntity/out:Person/out:PersonName/out:GivenName">
                  <xsl:for-each select="out:PartyEntity/out:Person/out:PersonName/out:GivenName">
                    < db:GIVEN_NAME>
                      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                     </db:GIVEN_NAME> 
                  </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
```

I can use something like below, But the output does not look nice, and I can have multiple given names in input, so this format wont work either.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(out:PartyEntity/out:Person/out:PersonName/out:GivenName[1],' ',out:PartyEntity/out:Person/out:PersonName/out:GivenName[2], ' ')"/>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Vivek

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you already set up? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, added my setup in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a template shoud work properly:

```
    <xsl:if test="out:GivenName">
        <db:GIVEN_NAME>
              <xsl:for-each select="out:GivenName">
                  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
         </db:GIVEN_NAME> 
    </xsl:if>
```

You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/pNmBxZz/1

Comment: Thanks a lot potame, you are awesome :)